# Return true elements from a Multi-checkbox true/ false array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, list, return

I am quite bad at php. I have a Multicheckbox that outputs an array this way:

```
Array
  (
   [value1] => true
   [value2] => false
   [value2] => false
   [value4] => false
   [value5] => true
   [value6] => false
  )
```

I would like to return an array with only the elements (values) that are true. Then I will apply this:

```
    $list_of_true_values = explode(',', $array_i_am_looking_for);
    return $list_of_true_values;
```

As in the end I want to return this: value1,value5.

Thanks'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rajat has said you can use the `array_keys()` function. I'd also add that if you're looking to get an output of `value1,value5`, you shouldn't use `explode()`, but rather, it's duel, `implode()`.

`return implode(",", array_keys($array, true));`

Is all you need.

---

As per your comment, if you'd like to wrap the keys in single quotes:

```
$keys = array_keys($array, true);
array_walk($keys, function(&$v, $k){$v = "'" . $v . "'";});
return (implode(",", $keys));
```

This is called [Anonymous (Lambda) Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: Thanks,I'll give you the correct answer as for the tip on implode. For some reason(I don't have many knowledge on php) it only works like this: 'true' and not true (array_keys($array, 'true'))

Comment: The reason is, the values in your `$array` are strings instead of actual booleans. Welcome to the wonderful world of PHP -- takes lots of practice! -- Have fun. ;)

Comment: Jordan, just one more thing, how can I return the values like this: 'value1','value5' instead of value1,value5?

Answer (score 2):

`array_keys($array, true);` will return array with keys with true value, which you need..

Comment: Thanks Rajat, I don't know why but only works like this: array_keys($array, 'true')

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically have `true`/`false` values, you can use PHP's [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) without a callback:

```
$values = array_filter($_POST['data']);
```

Without a callback function, `array_filter()` will filter out all of the "false" and empty values. Then, to get the keys from the list obtained, you can then use PHP's [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) as only the ones with "true" values will be in the `$values` array:

```
return array_keys($values);
```

In your exact specification, using the optional `$search_value` parameter of `array_keys()` may suffice, as Rajat has shown in his answer. However, I would suggest using `array_filter()` if you ever need to extend the list of values you want to keep or discard.